# create / alter stored procedure timing out during update / creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When creating or altering a SQL Server (2008+) stored procedure, does it "run" the contents of the stored procedure or simply check for syntax errors?  I've always been under the impression that it only checks for syntax.

I have a fairly simple stored procedure that calls several sub procedures, one of which connects to a linked server (mysql database) to pull information back from.  Making any routine updates will cause the entire procedure to run and often time out before the change is made.  I can confirm that it's running portions of the code as it's "pulling" data from the mysql tables.

I've been looking to see if it's a SSMS option or if it's just due to the fact that I'm using a linked server.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your connections, the only thing stooping it will be connection...open a new query window, put some select statement and check.. second thing postbthe entire error here

Comment: I'm not concerned about the contents of the query or performance of it, but rather if by default, SQL Server executes the stored procedure as part of a CREATE / ALTER.  If so, can this be disabled?

Comment: To my knowledge I have never had an CREATE / ALTER execute the stored procedure.  Are you sure you are not altering any tables?

Answer (score 0):

By default the query is sent to the parser.

"Query Parsing

When you pass a T-SQL query to the SQL Server system, the first place it goes to is the rel­ation­al engine. [1]

As the T-SQL arrives, it passes through a process that checks that the T-SQL is written correctly, that it's well formed. This process is known as query parsing. The output of the Parser process is a parse tree, or query tree (or even sequence tree). The parse tree represents the logical steps necessary to execute the query that has been requested."

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

The parsing process steps through the query. This is the step you are confusing as "Running" the sql.

Comment: So, the parsing is indeed "executing/running" the SQL code within the stored procedure, correct?